# Por que seletores com prefixos em uma mesma regra não funcionam?

Tags: css, seletores

Por exemplo se eu fizer isto para deixar o elemento que estiver em fullscreen com altura e largura igual 100% ele não funciona:

```
:fullscreen,
:full-screen,
:-webkit-full-screen,
:-moz-full-screen,
:-ms-fullscreen {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Mas se eu separar assim funciona:

```
:fullscreen {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

:full-screen {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

:-webkit-full-screen {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

:-moz-full-screen {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

:-ms-fullscreen {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

O mesmo ocorre com outros seletores, se eu fizer isto não funciona:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder, /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
::-moz-placeholder, /* Firefox 19+ (com ::) */
:-moz-placeholder, /* Firefox 18- (com :) */
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="testando">
```

Mas se separar funciona:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #f00;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ (com ::) */
  color: #f00;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- (com :) */
  color: #f00;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="testando">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isto são 3 seletores `a, b, c {}`, um grupo de seletores é chamado de "regra" (rule), quando um dos seletores dentro de uma regra é invalido então toda a "regra" é descartada.

Isto é informado em https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#logical-combination, neste trecho:

> **Warning:** The equivalence is true in this example because all the selectors are valid selectors.
>   If just one of these selectors were invalid, the entire selector list would be invalid.
>   This would invalidate the rule for all three heading elements, whereas in the former
>   case only one of the three individual heading rules would be invalidated.

Ou seja, se apenas um dos seletores for inválido, toda a lista de seletores será inválida, por exemplo, isto:

- Não agrupado (seletores em regras diferentes):

  ```
  h1 { font-family: sans-serif }
  h2..foo { font-family: sans-serif }
  h3 { font-family: sans-serif }
  ```
- Agrupado (seletores na mesma regra):

  ```
  h1, h2..foo, h3 { font-family: sans-serif }
  ```

Ambos acima são considerados diferentes, apesar de atingir o mesmo resultado. Na regra agrupada (`h1, h2..foo, h3`) o `h2..foo` é invalido fazendo descartar toda a regra, mas quando os seletores não estão agrupados, apenas a regra `h2..foo` será descartada.

Por exemplo se rodar em navegadores modernos isto:

```
:fullscreen,
:full-screen,
:-webkit-full-screen,
:-moz-full-screen,
:-ms-fullscreen {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

O `:fullscreen` é valido, mas os demais são inválidos, então eles a regra toda é descartada e assim nenhum dos seletores funcionarem.

Se rodar no IE11 o seletor `:-ms-fullscreen` é reconhecido, mas como esta em um grupo com outros seletores não suportados pelo IE11, então a regra toda será descartada.

Então é por este motivo que quando houver seletores inválidos para um determinado navegador que devemos separar em regras diferentes.