# Como criar um botão range com javascript puro

Tags: javascript

Como crio uma seekbar com javascript puro? Um exemplo abaixo:[image: Imagem]
**PS:** Eu não sei utilizar o jQuery, por isso gostaria do codigo em javascript puro

Comment: Saudações. Tem como você postar junto à pergunta o código que você já fez? Logo abaixo da pergunta existe o botão [edit]. Para inserir o código, basta copiá-lo no corpo da pergunta, selecioná-lo e pressionar `Ctrl+K` para formatá-lo corretamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como JavaScript puro não tem como, **sempre dependerá** de HTML e CSS, no caso um exemplo gerado com http://danielstern.ca/range.css/ seria isto (neste caso bastou usar o `input[type=range]` e `CSS`):

```css
input[type=range] {
    min-width: 100px; /* pode ajustar a largura aqui */
    margin: 9px 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #0071a9;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
              0 0 0 rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33),
                0 0 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.33);
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    border-radius: 28px;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -9px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #008cd2;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #0071a9;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
                0 0 0 rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    border-radius: 28px;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33),
                0 0 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.33);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #005680;
    border: 0 solid #010101;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
                0 0 0 rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #0071a9;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
                0 0 0 rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    border-radius: 28px;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33),
                0 0 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.33);
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: #0071a9;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background-color: #008cd2;
}
```

```html
<input type="range"> <input type="range"> <input type="range">
```

### Notas importantes

1. Existe repetição de CSS devido a "regras" (css rules) se tornarem inválidos quando existir um seletor inválido dentro uma regra (uma regra pode ter múltiplos seletores divididos por virgula ou dentro de `:not()` por exemplo):

   - [Por que seletores com prefixos em uma mesma regra não funcionam?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191155/3635)
2. O Safari e Chrome não tem suporte a uma propriedade equivalente ao `-moz-range-progress` por isto não tem como fazer uma cor a esquerda e outra a direita, talvez no futuro eu atualize a resposta.