# Por que os dois pontos duas vezes?

Tags: css3

```
 p::after
```

Para que serve os 2 pontos duas vezes (`::`)?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tem muitas postagens a respeito disso. Muitas delas estão neste pergunta que vc marcou como duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252589/8063

Answer (score 9):

Porque o `::after` e `::before` são pseudo elementos e não seletores, existem outros assim também, ou seja eles não afetam o elemento em si, mas sim um pseudo elemento, atuais pseudo-elementos

- `::after` cria um pseudo-elemento no final dentro do(s) elementos indicados na regra
- `::before` cria um pseudo-elemento no começo dentro do(s) elementos indicados na regra
- `::first-letter` afeta o estilo apenas da primeira letra
- `::first-line` afeta o estilo apenas da primeira linha
- `::selection` afeta apenas o estilo do que é selecionado
- `::backdrop` **<sup>(experimental)</sup>** Esse pseudo-elemento é uma caixa renderizada imediatamente abaixo do elemento superior (e acima do elemento logo abaixo desse elemento, caso exista algum), dentro da camada superior

Ou seja em nenhum dos casos é afetado o elemento em si diretamente, mas algo que não é um elemento real, como seleção, letra, linha ou então criará um elemento.

---

### É errado usar com apenas uma vez o `:`, como por exemplo `:after` ou `:before`?

Não é que seja errado, mas isso é uma maneira que podemos chamar de legado, antigamente tanto os pseudo-elementos quanto os seletores mais especificos usavam apenas uma vez o `:`, com o tempo para evitar confusões em pseudo elementos foi aplicado que deveria se usar `::`, mas os navegadores para evitar que sites antigos quebrem ainda dão suporte para o uso de `:after` e `:before`.

Creio que o ideal se deseja retro-compatibilidade e ao mesmo tempo evitar que no futuro os navegadores abandonem de vez `:after` e `:before`, seria usar separadamente assim:

```
regra1:after {
   /*regra1*/
}

regra1::after {
   /*regra1*/
}

regra2:before {
   /*regra2*/
}

regra2::before {
   /*regra2*/
}
```

Note que não recomendo que use isto:

```
 regra1:after, regra1::after {
   /*regra1*/
 }
```

Pois dois **seletores** em uma mesma **regra** podem se anular se no futuro um deles for inválido (por os navegadores removerem os **seletores legados** `:after` e `:before`), eu expliquei sobre isto nesta pergunta:

- [Por que seletores com prefixos em uma mesma regra não funcionam?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191155/3635)

Espero realmente que no futuro com novas funcionalidades do CSS coisas como variáveis ou até o uso de seletores inválidos em uma mesma regra sem falhar seja possível, pois só assim poderemos evitar repetição de código e mantermos alguma compatibilidade com navegadores mais antigos ao mesmo tempo, como em celulares mais antigos por exemplo.

Comment: Guilherme, aproveitando a pergunta do amigo, é errado fazer só com 1 _:_ ? não sei se é anormal mas aqui funciona.

Comment: @Guilherme editei a resposta, expliquei sobre a questão de funcionalidade legadas e mais alguns detalhes de como manter uma retro-compatibilidade, espero que ajude.

Answer (score 6):

Os pseudo elements podem ter esses dois pontos dependendo do versão do CSS

```
/* CSS3 syntax */
::after

/* CSS2 syntax */
:after
```

Para esclarecer mais um pouco existem os **Pseudo Elements** e as **Pseudo Classes**.

As *Pseudo Classes* sempre tem apenas um  **`:`**  já os *Pseudo Elements* podem ter apenas um **`:`** para funcionar em Browsers mais antigos ou dois **`::`** para as versões mais novas.

**Pseudo Elements**

- ::after
- ::before
- ::first-letter
- ::first-line
- ::selection

**Pseudo Classes** (aqui a sintaxe é sempre com apena um **`:`** )

- :active
- :checked
- :default
- :dir()
- :disabled
- :empty
- :enabled
- :first
- :first-child
- :first-of-type
- :fullscreen
- :focus
- :hover
- :indeterminate
- :in-range
- :invalid
- :lang()
- :last-child
- :last-of-type
- :left
- :link
- :not()
- :nth-child()
- :nth-last-child()
- :nth-last-of-type()
- :nth-of-type()
- :only-child
- :only-of-type
- :optional
- :out-of-range
- :read-only
- :read-write
- :required
- :right
- :root
- :scope
- :target
- :valid
- :visited

**Fonte:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elementos

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Answer (score 3):

Os dois pontos `::` são usados para criar um **[pseudo-elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elementos)** do elemento selecionado.

Como o próprio significado da palavra diz, **[pseudo](https://www.significados.com.br/pseudo/)** são elementos "falsos", que só existem virtualmente e não estão presentes no **[DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)**.

**Para que usar `::`?**

Quando você quer criar um outro elemento que estará dentro do escopo do elemento selecionado. É como se fosse um *clone-filho* do elemento real, com propriedades próprias. A vantagem é que você pode definir este *elemento virtual* da forma que quiser mantendo o mesmo escopo do elemento real, como se fosse ele mesmo.

**Exemplo:**

Execute o snippet abaixo e clique na área vermelha que é um *pseudo-elemento* do `checkbox`. Clicando nela, é a mesma coisa de estar clicando no próprio `checkbox`.

```css
#teste::after{
   content: 'Clique em mim, é como se estivesse clicando no checkbox';
   background: red;
   top: 20px;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="teste" />
```

**Limitações**

Por serem elementos apenas visuais não presentes no DOM, os *pseudo-elementos* não podem ser manipulados pelo JavaScript. Isso quer dizer que você não pode alterar as suas propriedades através de script, apenas por CSS.